# Ranking Posts with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay so I am using the punching bag gem to track the number of hits for my posts. What im trying to do is have a ranking system. So the most viewed post would be 1st and say the 10th viewed post would say 10th. Has anyone done this before or can give me a push in the right direction.

Right now on the posts I am showing the hit count with

```
<div class="votes">
      <strong>VIEWS</strong>
<%= @post.hits %>
```

and I am ranking them by just overall views and this is in my posts controller

```
def index
 if params[:sort_param] == "views"
  @posts = Post.sort_by_popularity('DESC')

  elsif params[:sort_param] == "likes"
  @posts = Post.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)

  else
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

end

I dont know what else code would be helpful for anyone. I will gladly add anymore code that would help.  Im just trying to figure out how to have a ranking on the show for the posts. So when you click on the post you see where that posts ranks on views. So for example you will see 450 views (I have this already) and Ranked 5th. I want people to be able to see where the posts ranks on view count. I just dont know where to begin for this

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What is exactly the problem?

Comment: @MarkoKacanski Im just trying to figure out how to have a ranking on the show for the posts. So when you click on the post you see where that posts ranks on views. So for example you will see 450 views (I have this already) and Ranked 5th. I want people to be able to see where the posts ranks on view count. I just dont know where to begin for this

Comment: Please update the question with the explanation, instead of sticking it in a comment. That keeps the information we need in one spot. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags, instead add the information where you would have if you'd entered it originally. We can see what changed if we need to. Putting information essential to the question in comments forces us to read every comment and try to piece everything together, which slows answers and makes it hard for others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that @post has the post you are trying to figure out the ranking for. Next step is to search the array you got with

```
  @posts = Post.sort_by_popularity('DESC')
```

to find where @post appears. You can try to do it like this:

```
@ranking = @posts.find_index(@post) + 1
```

Now you have the postion of your post relative to others with respect to hits. Plus one is because arrays start with zero

Comment: Thank you so much. This at least gives me a direction to head in. What would I use to call this in my post show?

Comment: You could use a regular erb output, i.e. "Ranking <%= @ranking %>" or something more fancy if you want custom formatting. I'm guessing you're new to Rails, so I suggest reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org. It won't take you long and it's written in a fun, approachable way. Happy coding.

Comment: Ya I tried that but nothing. Where do I put the @ranking = @posts.find_index(@post) + 1

Comment: That needs to go in the PostsController show method, look for "def show" and the associated code

Comment: Ya thats what I assumed and where I put it.But I got a undefined method "find_index" error. So I thought I put it in the wrong place

Comment: Then the punching bag method must be returning ActiveRecord relation, try using find(@post.id)